# How to build multiple apps in Android with only one project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I need to build multiple apps for our clients with just one project. I am currently doing it with product flavors in gradle. However, I am running across a problem. My apps must contain the same package name for the first two level. I mean to say that for example, all my apps should contain the package name com.ourcompany in their app package names. For example:

```
com.ourcompany.clienta.AppA
com.ourcompanu.clientb.AppB
```

I need a way to build these apps with totally different package names like for clientA, I could go like com.clientacompany.AppA, for client B, it will be like com.clientbcompany.AppB. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `applicationId`:

```
productFlavors {
    vanilla {
        applicationId "com.clientacompany.app.a"
    }

    chocolate {
        applicationId "com.clientbcompany.app.b"
    }
}
```

I do not recommend mixed case, which is why I eliminated that in the values.